# How do I know if I've hit a checkpoint recently?

Tags: diablo-iii

If I need to peel myself away from Diablo III, it's usually convenient to do so at a checkpoint so when I quit and rejoin I'm plopped down right back where I was (or equivalently in a randomly generated area).  The *Checkpoint!* messages though are quickly forgotten unless one cares about them (and I usually don't).

How do I know where my most recent checkpoint is (without quitting and rejoining, possibly losing a fair bit of progress through a level)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to determine what your checkpoint is.  You just have to pay attention to the messages.  After running through the same area a few times, it should be fairly easy to memorize where the checkpoints are.  They are always near an entrance of some sort, with a couple of exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

The one way of checking the last checkpoint without leaving the game is dying. After revive you spawn on your last checkpoint.